# Forzar Actualización automática de App Store iOs Nativa

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, app-store

tengo una aplicación en App Store (iOs Nativa Swift) y requiero hacer que la aplicación valide que hay una nueva actualización y no permitir que se use sin antes actualizar a la ultima versión.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar este repo: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren

Lo configuras en tu `AppDelegate` y de acuerdo a tus necesidades configuras si es requerido o no actualizar la App.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    checkAppUpdate()
}

func checkAppUpdate(){
    //Instancias la variable
    let siren = Siren.shared
    //Agregas las reglas a tu elección 
    let skipableRule = Rules(promptFrequency: .immediately, forAlertType: .skip)
    let annoyingRule = Rules(promptFrequency: .immediately, forAlertType: .option)
    let forceRule = Rules(promptFrequency: .immediately, forAlertType: .force)
    //Agregas las reglas
    siren.rulesManager = RulesManager(majorUpdateRules: forceRule,
                                      minorUpdateRules: annoyingRule,
                                      patchUpdateRules: skipableRule,
                                      revisionUpdateRules: skipableRule,
                                         showAlertAfterCurrentVersionHasBeenReleasedForDays: 0)
//Obtienes el resultado de la conexión con el AppStore de si existe o no una nueva version.
siren.wail { results in
        switch results {
        case .success(let updateResults):
            print("App Store Version: ", updateResults.model.version)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    }
```

En el manual del repo tienes los detalles de cada opción para la configuración.