# Cómo puedo validar si hay una actualización disponible tanto en PlayStore como en AppStore?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Explayándome mas, tengo una app hecha en react native y quisiera saber si hay una forma de comparar la version que tengo instalada en el dispositivo, con la version subida de la app tanto en PlayStore como en AppStore. Logré obtener la información de la app instalada del dispositivo, pero no sé como obtener dicha información de la PlayStore como de la AppStore. Y de esa forma poder realizar una validación para que el usuario no pueda utilizar la app mientras que no lo actualice.

Comment: En iOS utilizo `Siren` te puede servir: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373500/forzar-actualización-automática-de-app-store-ios-nativa/373521#373521

Comment: Puedes implementar el siguiente comportamiento si tienes un backend, muy fácil: en la splash o la primera pantalla, pides a backend la versión actual y la compruebas con la que tiene el usuario, o directamente le dices a backend la versión del usuario y que te diga si es la última o no, en función de eso muestras un diálogo no cancelable que te envía a la play store para actualizar.

Comment: Recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.